# How to switch on/off relay using serial port on raspberrry pi?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, serial-port

Inputs to relay must be a 8 bit number (something like `00000001` or `00000010`) which will be pass on the serial port communication to switch on and off the relays, but the following code is not working ...

```
import serial 
ser = serial.Serial( port='/dev/ttyUSB0', baudrate=9600,\parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, timeout=0)
if ser.isOpen()==True:
    print("device opened")
    print("connected to: " + ser.portstr)
    command = b'\x1'
    ser.read()
    while True:
        ser.write(command)
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: need to configure relay with 8bit hex code  using raspberry pi so that relay will switch on and off